# Audible crackle/hiss/noise when using Homeplug

Tags: powerline-networking

I get an audible hiss when data is being transferred on the power line network. For instance, if I'm listening to headphone on my PC, if I transfer a file or do anything which requires data transfer, I can literally hear the data coming down.

It seems the mains is causing the hiss, if I'm listening to headphones on my phone and I plug in the charger I can here the hiss through a that device as well!

How do I resolve this?